# Machine not connecting to Github

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to follow along with a tutorial video and I am unable to get past the 1st step of creating the project using react next js. Within Visual Studio Code I enter the following then am giving the response -

after opening vscode and opening a terminal I type

-npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss ( then my projects name )

---

After I press enter, the files start to download, but then I receive an error as stated below

-Downloading files for example with-tailwindcss. This might take a moment.

? Could not download "with-tailwindcss" because of a connectivity issue between your machine and GitHub.
Do you want to use the default template instead? » (Y/n)

---

I am unable to start the project because I am receiving the error that there is a connectivity issue between my machine and github. I do not understand why because I have never seen this error before prior to using the command npx- create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss

If I type npx create (project name) I do not receive an error and there is no connectivity issue between my machine and github.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I have been browsing everywhere and cannot find the solution. Thank you !

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you pls write specifically about the problem currently you are facing?

Comment: I made an edit so that my issue is more clear. my issue is that when i use npx- create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss (project name) to start my project I encounter a connectivity issue between my machine and github

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried it? ```https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs```Installing tailwind after creating the app.

Comment: This one works, but I've been trying to install v2, which is where I get the error. v3 works, but v2 doesnt. I should have noted this in the description above.

the follow along tutorial, which the person streamed live yesterday, used v2 and it seemed to work for him and everyone else in the live chat. I was the only one experiencing this issue 

when I use v3, the project ends up looking different  due to stylizing issues etc. I deleted all the css to try to make it look the same, but that did not help. So I would like to try to use tailwind v2 if possible